# 301 redirect with multiple URL's using .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, redirect, http-status-code-301

I have built a brand new website to replace an old website for a business

how do i use a .htaccess file to redirect the urls

eg.

www.business.com.au  -> www.newbusiness.com.au
www.business.com.au/about.htm  -> www.newbusiness.com.au/about-us

so on and so forth for all the pages so that the old links point to the new links and the home page on the old site points to the home page of the new site.

thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the paths on the old homepage are different from the paths on the new one, I suppose you would use a hand full of Redirect-Directives:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^$ http://newbusiness.com.au/ [R=301,L]

Redirect 301 /about.htm http://www.newbusiness.com.au/about-us
Redirect 301 /contact.htm http://www.newbusiness.com.au/new-contact
```

and so on.

Comment: Would this be classified as a 301 redirect?

Comment: To be on the safe side you can specify which code to use:
Redirect 301 /about.htm http://www.newbusiness.com.au/about-us

Comment: It is sort of working, the home page redirects correctly but the other pages do not seem to be working correctly the url seems to be mutating and adding extra characters from somewhere.

Comment: Upon further inspection, I can see that for some reason it is adding the directory after the domain name. This may be becasue it is going from a standard html site to a wordpress site I am not sure.
the website www.apola.asn.au redirects to www.apola.com.au and then www.apola.asn.au/about.htm is supposed to redirect to www.apola.com.au/about-apola but it is for some reason redirecting to www.apola.com.auapola-asn/about.htm im not sure if this helps

Comment: Would you send us your .htaccess?

Comment: This is all my .htaccess contains.

RewriteEngine on
Redirect 301 / http://www.apola.com.au
Redirect 301 /index.html http://www.apola.com.au
Redirect 301 /about.htm http://www.apola.com.au/about-apola/
Redirect 301 /directory.htm http://www.apola.com.au/about-apola/apola-officers/
Redirect 301 /links.htm http://www.apola.com.au/about-apola/clients/
Redirect 301 /mship.htm http://www.apola.com.au/about-apola/membership/
Redirect 301 /notice.htm http://www.apola.com.au/home/apola-newsletter/
Redirect 301 /safety.htm http://www.apola.com.au/beach-water-safety/

Comment: Have you tried putting a http:// in front of the destination links? If thats not the cause it still is best practice.

Comment: Sorry yes it is already there, the formatting of stack overflow has changed it for some reason. each link is "http:// www. apola.com.au/......" without the spaces obviously

Comment: Try changing the "Redirect 301 / http:// apola.com.au" to "Redirect 301 /index.html http:// apola.com.au"

Comment: This has stopped the redirect completely

Comment: That's odd. Try exchanging the line "Redirect 301 / ..." with "RewriteRule ^$ http:// apola.com.au/ [R=301,L]" (watch out for the space after http://)

Comment: Im not sure what you mean with that one how should the file be formatted.

Comment: That has worked for the home page but not for about.htm or any of the others and i can still access the old home page by going to apola.asn.au/index.html in short it is only redirecting apola.asn.au to apola.com.au none of the other pages or links

Answer (score 1):

```
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.business.com.au$
  RewriteRule (.*)$ http://www.newbusiness.com.au/$1 [R=301,L]
```