# Redirection with .htaccess for many pages by Regex?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I would like a redirection for many pages (10 000).
For example, I need :

`example.com/home-office-london/`
to
`example.com/office-london/`

and

`example.com/home-office-paris/` to
`example.com/office-paris/`

I want this with a 301 redirection by `.htaccess`.

Can you help me please?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [301 redirect with multiple URL's using .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27369539/301-redirect-with-multiple-urls-using-htaccess)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your examples it would seem you are removing `home-` from the start of the URL-path. These URLs consist of a single path segment and end with a slash.

You can do this using mod_rewrite (since I assume you are already using mod_rewrite) at the top of the root `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect "/home-<anything>/" to "/<anything>/"
RewriteRule ^home-([^/]+/)$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Test first with a 302 (temporary) redirect to avoid potential caching issues.

Answer (score 0):

That's ok for me. Thanks a lot.

```
RewriteRule ^home-office-([^/]+/)$ /office-$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: You can include `office-` in the capturing group to save repetition. Eg. `RewriteRule ^home-(office-[^/]+/)$ /$1 [R=301,L]`.